Likelihood test on simple regression
I'm working through Introduction to Econometrics by Gary Koop, but I'm slightly struggling to make sense of a question from chapter 4.
It asks you to carry out a liklihood ratio test of $H_0 :\beta=0$ for the simple regression model $Y_i=\alpha +\beta X_i+\varepsilon_i$. It asks you to outline the restricted and unrestricted models, set out their maximum likelihood estimates, and then derive the likelihood ratio $\lambda$.
The first part is straightforward in that we have:
The unrestricted model is $Y^{UR}_i = \alpha +\beta X_i+\varepsilon_i$
The restricted model is $Y^R_i = \alpha +\varepsilon_i$
We then have the liklhood functions of these given by:
$$L^{UR}(\hat\alpha_{UR},\hat\beta_{UR}) = \dfrac{1}{(2\pi \hat\sigma_{UR}^2)^{\frac{N}{2}}}\text{exp} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2\hat\sigma_{UR}^2}\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat\alpha_{UR} - \hat\beta_{UR} X_i)^2 \right )$$
$$L^{R}(\hat\alpha_R,\hat\beta_R) = \dfrac{1}{(2\pi \hat\sigma_R^2)^{\frac{N}{2}}}\text{exp}
 \left ( \dfrac{1}{2\hat{\sigma_R^2}}\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat\alpha_R)^2 \right )$$
However, at this point I get a bit stuck. I know that the liklihood ratio is given by:
$$\lambda = \dfrac{L^{R}(\hat\alpha_R,\hat\beta_R)}{L^{UR}(\hat\alpha_{UR},\hat\beta_{UR}) }=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{(2\pi \hat\sigma_R^2)^{\frac{N}{2}}}\text{exp}
 \left ( \dfrac{1}{2\hat{\sigma_R^2}}\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat\alpha_R)^2 \right )}{\dfrac{1}{(2\pi \hat\sigma_{UR}^2)^{\frac{N}{2}}}\text{exp} \left ( \dfrac{1}{2\hat\sigma_{UR}^2}\sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat\alpha_{UR} - \hat\beta_{UR} X_i)^2 \right )}$$
But I'm not sure how to make any sense of this?

Do you have the $y_i$ and the $X_i$?

@DemetriPananos Nope, it seems more of a theoretical question. The questions ends by asking you to discuss the difference between testing $H_0$ using the $-2ln(\lambda)$ test statistic and the usual t-test statistic.
